# How to check if string contains only letters, numbers and double backslash

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a method to check if string contains **only** numbers, letters, specific characters (`+_-/`) and only double backslashes (`\\`).

example:

`a2b/\`  - false

`d+sd\\ff` - true

I tried this:

```
stringExample.matches("^[a-z-A-Z-0-9 +_-/]+");
```

...but it doesn't match a double backslash (`\\`).

Comment: First, it's a double **backslash**, not a double slash. And are you sure that you want it to be double? Some people think the Java string literal `"abc\\def"` contains a double backslash, when in fact this is only an escaping notation, and that string contains only a single backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since backslashes are generally used as the escape character, they have to be escapsed as well via a `\\` to represent a single slash, so two consecutive backslashes would use `\\\\`.

So for your expression to allow those characters and only sets of two backslashes, you could use :

```
stringExample.matches("^([\\w\\s+\\-/]|(\\\\\\\\))+$");
```

This can be explained as follows :

```
^             # Beginning of expression
(             # Beginning of group
[\\w\\s+\\-/] # Match any alphanumeric or underscore (\w), space (\s), or +, - or \
|             # OR
(\\\\\\\\)    # An explicit double-slash
)             # End of group
+             # Allow one or more instances of the previous group
$             # End of expression
```

Comment: warning your regexp doesn't even compile you need to double each backslash \w should be \\w...

Comment: Thanks for that. I had originally just used the expression itself there without the `matches()` call and kept it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

\ is a special character. It has functionality in regex (escaping). This means that you need to escape it in order to capture it as it's own character.

\\ would mean '\' as a character

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
private static void checkdoubleSlash(String a) {
        if(a.contains("\\\\"))
            System.out.println("True");
        else
            System.out.println("False");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the pattern as you wrote it doesn't compile:

```
^[a-z-A-Z-0-9 +_-/]+
```

Because `_-/` is interpreted as a range, but that's invalid.
It's better to move the `-` to the end, to make it not be a range:

```
^[a-z-A-Z-0-9 +_/-]+
```

And also remove the duplicated `-`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 +_/-]+
```

Next, notice that `[...]` is for single characters. And you don't to allow single `\`, only double `\\`, so that's a two-character pattern.
To achieve this, the regular expression should be something like:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 +_/-]|double-backslash)+
```

I wrote "double-backslash there because this needs a bit of extra explanation. To write that, is not simply `\\`, because in Java strings you need to escape backslashes, so `\\\\`. And in regular expressions, you need to escape them again. So the final regular expression you need is:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9 +_/-]|\\\\\\\\)+
```

With some unit tests:

```
public boolean testMatch(String s) {
    return s.matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9 +_/-]|\\\\\\\\)+");
}

@Test
public void should_match_string_with_double_backslash() {
    assertTrue(testMatch("d+sd\\\\ff"));
}

@Test
public void should_not_match_string_with_single_backslash() {
    assertFalse(testMatch("a2b/\\"));
}
```